# Find $k$ such that $\frac{1}{(1+x)^k}+\frac{1}{(1+y)^k}+\frac{1}{(1+z)^k}\geq\frac{3}{2^k}$ for $xyz=1$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution

> Find all $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that for all $xyz=1$, $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^+$, we
>   have
>   $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^k}+\frac{1}{(1+y)^k}+\frac{1}{(1+z)^k}\geq\frac{3}{2^k}.$$

If we set $$x=\frac{a}{b},\,y=\frac{b}{c},\,z=\frac{c}{a},$$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, then the inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{a^k}{(a+b)^k}+\frac{b^k}{(b+c)^k}+\frac{c^k}{(c+a)^k}\geq\frac{3}{2^k}.$$ For $k=1$ this is obviously false, as we take $b\to0$ and $c\to\infty$. In an olympiad test I saw that the case $k=\sqrt3$ is true (though I do not know how to prove that). I then thought that maybe this is true for all $k>1$. Am I correct and how do I prove it?

Comment: Your example for $k=1$ asymptotically leads to the inequality $2 > 3/2$ which is correct, no? So why is the case $k=1$ obviously not true?

Comment: Taking $x=y=10$ and $z=1/100$ as suggested by Michael's approach shows that it doesn't hold for $k=1$ though. You need to let two numbers be large (and one small) to not exceed $3/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is $k_{min}=\log_23$.

Let $x=e^a$, $y=e^b$, $z=e^c$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+e^x)^k}$.

Hence, $a+b+c=0$ and we need to prove that

$$\sum_{cyc}f(a)\geq3f\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)$$
But $f''(x)=\frac{2ke^x(ke^x-1)}{(1+e^x)^{k+2}}\geq0$ for all $k\geq1$ and $x\geq0$.

Thus, by Vasc's RCF Theorem for all $k\geq1$ it's enough to prove our inequality

for $y=x$ and $z=\frac{1}{x^2}$, which gives $\frac{2}{(1+x)^k}+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^k}\geq\frac{3}{2^k}$
and for $x\rightarrow+\infty$ we get $k\geq\log_23$.

Comment: What's Vasc's RCF theorem?

Comment: @TMM see here: https://www.scribd.com/document/74289577/RCF-Theorem-Proof

Comment: You may want to add a brief description of this theorem to your answer, so that it is clear what identity regarding $f$ you are using. I also still don't see how exactly you're applying it here - where are you showing/using that the average of the variables equals $s$ whatever $s$ may be? (The quoted document has this assumption that the average must be equal to $s$.)

Comment: @TMM I fixed my post. See now, please.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Still it could be useful to state the RCF theorem in your answer as well, as it doesn't seem like such a well-known result. Also I'm not sure what "cyc" means - why not just write $f(a) + f(b) + f(c)$?

Comment: @TMM Because it's easier and I'm just used to it.

Comment: Then how do I prove that the case $k=\log_2 3$ is true?

Comment: @Yuxiao Xie It's just calculus: let $g(x)=\frac{2}{(1+x)^k}+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^k}-1$, where $k=\log_23$. Hence, $g'(x)=0$ for $x=1$ and for $x=3.0847...$, which gives that $x_{min}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=0$, which ends the proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks! I was thinking of some elementary proof for this.

Answer (score -1):

As shown below, an easy partial result is that $k_{\text{min}} \ge 1$.

Let $k$ be fixed with $0 <  k < 1$.

WIth the substitutions

$$x=\frac{a}{b},\,y=\frac{b}{c},\,z=\frac{c}{a}$$

let $a = b = 1$, and let $c \to 0^{+}$. Then

\begin{align*}
\;&\frac{a^k}{(a+b)^k}+\frac{b^k}{(b+c)^k}+\frac{c^k}{(c+a)^k}\\[6pt]
&\to \;\frac{1}{2^k} + 1 + 0\\[6pt]
&=\;\frac{1 + 2^k}{2^k}\\[6pt]
&<\;\frac{1 + 2}{2^k}\\[6pt]
&=\;\frac{3}{2^k}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

It follows that $k_{\text{min}} \ge 1$, as claimed.

However, as shown below, the reasoning by which the OP (Yuxiao Xie) excluded the value $k=1$ is not correct.

Suppose $k = 1$. Then as$\;\,b \to 0^{+}$ and $\,c \to \infty$,

\begin{align*}
\;&\frac{a^k}{(a+b)^k}+\frac{b^k}{(b+c)^k}+\frac{c^k}{(c+a)^k}\\[6pt]
&\to\;1+ 0 + 1\\[6pt]
&=\;2\\[6pt]
&>\;\frac{3}{2}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

which doesn't break the required inequality, hence the value $k=1$ is not automatically excluded.

In fact, I suspect that $k_{\text{min}} = 1$.

Update: It's not true, as I had previously thought, that $k_{\text{min}} = 1$.

As a simple counterexample, let $(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{1}{8},2,4\right)$. Then

$$\frac{1}{(1+x)}+\frac{1}{(1+y)}+\frac{1}{(1+z)} = \frac{64}{45} < \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: The first part follows from Michael's answer and my second comment to the question, while I already pointed out the second part of your answer in my first comment. And your final conclusion is wrong, provided Michael did not make a mistake.

Comment: @TMM: I didn't really follow Michael's answer, but from what I was able to understand, it seemed that he proved the specified inequality holds when $k \ge \log_2{3}$. I certainly might have missed something, but it didn't seem that he showed that the specified inequality holds _only_ for values of $k \ge \log_2{3}$.  The point of my post was to show, in a very elementary way, that if $0 < k < 1$, there are values of $x,y,z$ for which specified inequality fails.

Comment: @TMM: Also, with regard to my "final conclusion". I clearly indicated that it was a _guess_, and as shown in my update, I later found a counterexample which disproved that guess.

Comment: So I think my post added at least _some_ value to the discussion.